Using Testcontainers.Oracle with .NET Core Identity - login issue
I am trying to use an Oracle testcontainer to test an API built with Microsoft .NET Core Identity Framework.  The API itself is working and created a migration to build the database in Oracle, which runs fine on the development server.
However, when I try to run the migration against the test container instance, it fails with the following error:
System.NotSupportedException
HResult=0x80131515
Message=Required user does not exists or invalid username/password provided

The sample code is below.
The exception is thrown while executing dbContext.Database.Migrate(), which should create the ASP.NET Identity tables in the test Oracle instance, but instead it reports the invalid user/name password.
    using DotNet.Testcontainers.Builders;
    using DotNet.Testcontainers.Containers;
    using Identity.Models;
    using Identity.Test.Abstractions;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using Xunit;

    namespace Identity.Test
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class BaseTest
        {
            private static string Database = "MYDB";
            private static string Username = "MYUSER";
            private static string Password = "R@nd0mP@$$word!";
            private static ushort OraclePort = 1521;

            private WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
            private IContainer _container;
            protected HttpClient _client { get; set; }

            [OneTimeSetUp]
            public async Task OneTimeSetup()
            {
                try
                {

                    // Set up Testcontainers SQL Server container
                    IContainer _container = new ContainerBuilder()
                        .WithImage("gvenzl/oracle-free:23.4-slim-faststart")
                        .WithPortBinding(OraclePort, true)
                        .WithEnvironment("ORACLE_DATABASE", Database)
                        .WithEnvironment("APP_USER", Username)
                        .WithEnvironment("APP_USER_PASSWORD", Password)
                        .WithEnvironment("ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD", Password)
                        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(OraclePort))
                        .Build();

                    await _container.StartAsync();

                    var host = _container.Hostname;
                    var port = _container.GetMappedPublicPort(OraclePort);
                    var connectionString = $"CONNECTION TIMEOUT=6100;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST={host})(PORT={port}))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = FREE)));USER ID={Username};PASSWORD={Password};Pooling=true";


                    _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                    {
                        builder.ConfigureTestServices
                            (
                                    services =>
                                    {
                                        services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<JwtAuthDbContext>));
                                        services.AddDbContext<JwtAuthDbContext>(options => options.UseOracle(connectionString));
                                    }
                            );
                    });

                    using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
                    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<JwtAuthDbContext>();

                    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
            [OneTimeTearDown]
            public async Task OneTimeTearDown()
            {
                await _container.StopAsync();
                await _container.DisposeAsync();
                _factory.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }


